# How is this C++ function returning two values?

Tags: c++, constructor, return, initializer-list, stdinitializerlist

Please explain how this function is returning two values. It is taking an array and returning the two numbers from the array whose sum is equal to target sum.

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<nums.size()-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i+1; j<nums.size(); j++)
        {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
            {
                a = i;
                b = j;
            }
        }
    }
    return {a, b};
    }
};
```

Comment: its not returning 2 values, its returning a single vector with 2 elements

Answer (score 7):

The class `std::vector` has a constructor with the first parameter of a specialization of the template `std::initializer_list<T>` and that correspondingly accepts an initializer list.

```
vector(initializer_list<T>, const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

Such a constructor is called *initializer-list constructor*.

So when in the return statement there is used a braced list of objects of the same type, the compiler tries to use this braced list as an argument of the constructor that accepts an initializer list to build the returned object of the specified return type.

In fact, under the hood there is used the following action:

```
std::vector<int> temporary_object = { a, b };
```

So the function returns only one object (container) of the type `std::vector<int>` (the returned type of the function) that contains two elements of the type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The function returns a vector : `vector<int> twoSum(...) { ... }`.
The line `return {a, b};` calls the constructor of a vector, initialized with two values.
This is equivalent to:

```
vector<int> myVector;
myVector.push_back(a);
myVector.push_back(b);
return myVector;
```

Comment: Not quite. This (not-)equivalent code might require 2 reallocations because it's possible (and it usually happens) that `myVector` is reserved 0 space when it's declared, just 1 upon the first `push_back`, and just 2 after the second `push_back`. Returning a `vector` by `{...}` does not suffer this.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. I was pointing the misunderstanding of the post owner (two values returned), so I came with a simple approach not to confuse him/her. However, you are right and it's interesting to point it if someone want to have a better understanding of why return directly `{a, b}`.

Comment: ok, fine, but is suggest that you explain what you mean by "equivalent". That code is not equivalent performance-wise, nor side effect-wise for the readings i explained.